# Load data in background once initial website is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a feed with posts and comments.

I only show the last 5 comments and the other are css-hidden, they are revealed when clicking on "Show all comments".

Currently my thinking is to fetch those comments (ajax) when the "Show" link is clicked.

Is there any way to load those comments in the background automatically, immediately after the initial page has loaded?

**Update**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='post'>This is a post</div>
    <div class='comment hidden'>This is a comment</div> # To load asynchronously
    <div class='comment hidden'>This is a comment</div> # To load asynchronously
    <div class='comment hidden'>This is a comment</div> # To load asynchronously
    <div class='comment hidden'>This is a comment</div> # To load asynchronously
    <a href='#'>Show all comments</a>
    <div class='comment'>This is a comment</div>
    <div class='comment'>This is a comment</div>
    <div class='comment'>This is a comment</div>
    <div class='comment'>This is a comment</div>
    <div class='comment'>This is a comment</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing stream table is the best way for doing that.

The idea behind StreamTable.js is to initially populate minimum rows (maybe 10 or 20) and after that it streams data silently in the background and update the table. This ensures that the page loads immediately and is also usable immediately for all operations. It maybe safe to assume that if the user remains on the same page for a little while longer, then the user is most probably going to perform some operation on table like search, page navigation, etc. So we can delay the process of streaming data to say 2 seconds after the page has loaded. Its also important to ensure that all the data streamed must be usable immediately. For example, after 2 seconds, if we have streamed 1000 rows, they should all be searchable and paginated.

For more detail, Go through this [link](https://github.com/jiren/StreamTable.js)
This is one of the best js library.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body onload="script();">
```

or

```
document.onload = function ...
```

or

```
window.onload = function ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I might consider waiting to load the additional comments (or at least the majority of them) until the user performs a given action such as clicking the "Show" link. This prevents your page from loading (even in the background) a ton of comments the user never requests/needs to see. This also helps reduce the data load of your app if any of your users are on a mobile device.

As far as implementation, you can take your pick of JS/Ajax tools (vanilla, jquery, angular, vuejs, react, etc) and setup a click event that appends X more comments to your initial list.

Hope that helps!